# How to get remove water from a submarine that is submerged

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure

How can water be removed from a submarine that is submerged?

If a submarine is opened, while it is submerged, water would get in because of the difference between the pressures.

For example, I have seen that there is a diving room in submarines, these rooms are in direct contact with the sea but the level of the water remains steady.

Can anyone explain for me this phenomenon?

If just the water level was steady, why don't we threw the water directly to the sea?

[image: explanation]

Comment: What about pumps? I'm sure they operate the flow with different pumps. That's what you normally do with you have to overcome a pressure and gravity is not on your side (I'm not expert in the field)

Comment: i made a change on the question, please i would like u to read it @Brian Drummond

Comment: Is this of any help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_trunk

Comment: thank you Paul :) , i think it talks about a separate room, it's like a second submarine, it has no direct contact with the water, what i ask about really is how can we have a stable surface of a direct contact with the sea water and a normal airy room

Comment: So you mean like a hatch that is opened and you see the level of water when you are inside? Like an "ice-fishing" level where the ice would be the walls?

Comment: If so, I think you are trying to describe an air-lock. But that doesn't keep a stable surface, but it is rather flooded so that the diver can get out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlock

Comment: exactly, like the water would not get out the ice hatch, the same thing would happen in the submarine room, it's like a cave in the bottom of the sea, and has an airy room where the divers would go to. i've seen this once in a picture but just can't explain it by physics

Comment: And you can also see this thread: https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-get-out-of-a-submarine-in-depth-without-the-inflow-of-water-inside-it

Comment: You're welcome. I hope it helps!

Comment: -1 for the crappy diagram.  It's out of focus, and there is no excuse for it being rotated.  No, I'm not going to tilt my head to read it.  Closing since now I don't know what is being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you set it up, you'll need a two-door lock room.  For example, torpedos are placed in the firing tube in air, the rear hatch is locked, and the tube is flooded. Only then is the torpedo launched.

Divers can and do exit submarines which have a similar lock room for people. The same basic sequence is performed -- and reversed when the divers return.  Here's a great photo  [Seal entry to sub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airlock#/media/File:SEAL_Delivery_Vehicle_Team_(SDV)_2.jpg)

Comment: you could have an open pool if you maintained the air pressure high enough. Obviously only practical at extremely shallow depths..

Answer (score 0):

The picture that you have drawn is not of submarine but a diving bell (check up wikipedia). In a diving bell the pressure inside the chamber balances the hydrostatic pressure of water and hence the water level inside the diving bell does not rise. You have see this if you push a glass tumbler into a tub.

In a true submarine, the water in the balast tanks is vented by pushing in compressed air from reservoirs. However this is not the only way submarines can control their depth.